# Wired Keyboard UEFI

Tags: boot, usb, keyboard, uefi

I am dual booting Linux (Manjaro) and Windows 10. My keyboard (link below) doesn't power on during the boot phase of my computer meaning I cannot enter the UEFI settings or select my desired OS (Linux or Windows 10) in the grub boot menu. This completely defeats the point of dual booting if I can still only access one OS.

My keyboard utilises two seperate USB ports (I figured one might be for the backlighting, although I am not sure).

Now, the weirdest part is the stock, wireless keyboard that came with the computer works! The wireless keyboard uses a transceiver plugged in (via USB) to the computer.

I have searched my computer UEFI settings for a 'USB Legacy Mode' with no luck, I figured someone maybe able to help me out.

My question is how to configure my computer to allow the use of my keyboard before booting into the OS (so I can enter UEFI settings/select OS via grub).

My computer was purchased from HP ([original specs](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c03822238)), it has been upgraded since then (CPU, GPU, PSU). Perhaps this affects the settings available in UEFI.

[Keyboard](https://steelseries.com/gaming-keyboards/apex-350)

Motherboard: MS-7826 (Kaili)

Comment: Your keyboard seems to be behind an embedded USB hub. It is possible that your old UEFI does not support hubs. Try to figure this out, get a stand-alone USB2.0 hub, and put your wireless working KB behind it. Then try if your UEFI recognizes the combination.

Comment: Also, could you add to your question what kind of USB your keyboard is, as it gets reported by USBView.exe utility under Windows.

Comment: @AliChen Ill see if I can get my hands on a USB 2.0 hub (you mean just a USB splitter kinda thing, right?). However, right now the wireless KB dongle is attached to the built in USB outputs on the non working KB, not directly to the PC.

Comment: So, it means that the wifi dongle does work behind the hub when in UEFI, right? Then the problem likely is in your fancy proprietary keyboard, it likely has some extra (or wrong) stuff in USB descriptors that UEFI does not like or recognize. Again, if you try the USBView utility, does it display your keyboard without any flags?